# how to set up eclipse photon CDT for u-boot

Tags: eclipse, u-boot

Has anyone managed to get u-boot to compile using the latest 2021 release of eclipse.  I am using import makefile type and I know there are some gyrations you have to go through to use custom cross compilers but it still is unable to compile.  Just curious what steps where used to set up the project.  Samples I have seen are with older eclipse versions and much has changed.

Comment: Eclipse Photon (4.8) is not the latest version of Eclipse it is 4 years and 14 releases old, the current version is Eclipse 2021-12 (4.22).

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I did mean the 2021 version.  Had Photon on the mind for some reason.